# Using psql in Java

Tags: java, sql

I'm using PostgreSQL in Java and I want to create a database structure.

How I can run a SQL script using psql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code that works like psql:

```
public void ejecutarScript(String file) throws IOException, SQLException {
    Statement st3 = conexion.createStatement();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String str;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(str + "\n ");
    }
    in.close();
    st3.executeUpdate(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same way you would any other SQL script, just make sure you've set the dialogue to PSQL.  If you're using JDBC make sure you're using the driver found [here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/)